# NLog log to a specific target mentioned in the config

Tags: c#, .net, nlog

I have a console application with the below NLog configuration

```xml
<targets async="true">
    <target name="Afile" xsi:type="File" fileName="c:\users\a\Logs\ALog.txt" />
    <target name="Bfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="c:\users\a\Logs\BLog.txt" />
    <target name="Cfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="c:\users\a\Logs\CLog.txt" />
    <target name="Dfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="c:\users\a\Logs\DLog.txt" />
    <target name="Efile" xsi:type="File" fileName="c:\users\a\Logs\ELog.txt" />
    <target name="Ffile" xsi:type="File" fileName="c:\users\a\Logs\FLog.txt" />
    <target name="Gfile" xsi:type="File" fileName="c:\users\a\Logs\GLog.txt" />
 </targets>

   <rules>
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="Afile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="Bfile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="Cfile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="Dfile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="Efile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="Ffile" />
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="Gfile" />
  </rules>
```

The console application takes one argument anywhere from A to F, based on the argument defined during execution, I would like to write the logs to a particular log file
So , if my application was executed with argument A, I would want my application to write to target Afile and correspondingly for other arguments

Comment: Why use NLog at all?  Seems to just make things more complicated for your scenario.  If the log file doesn't change during execution and depends entirely upon a runtime argument, using NLog to write a file seems overkill.

Comment: We are not set on Nlog yet, Whats your recommendation then?

Comment: But I would also like to know if its doable

Comment: If you want to use NLog, it would be better to [configure NLog through code](https://github.com/nlog/NLog/wiki/Configuration-API).

Comment: Amy, this one is adding a target to the configuration during runtime . Which is probably one way of doing it. But what if i already have it configured. Can i pick a specific target configuration based on the argument passed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```xml
<targets async="true">
   <target name="onefile" xsi:type="File" fileName="c:\users\a\Logs\${gdc:item=CmdArg}Log.txt" />
</targets>

<rules>
   <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="onefile" />
</rules>
```

Then configure the following variable before doing any logging:

```
NLog.GlobalDiagnosticsContext.Set("CmdArg","someValue");
```

See also https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Gdc-layout-renderer

Comment: Worked like a charm.. Thanks